# Lists.asmx item person not in UserGroup.asmx GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb method

Tags: 2007, list, web-services, user-profile, user

I am using Lists.asmx's `GetListItems` method, then I'm using info from UserGroup.asmx's `GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb` method to get more user details about a person in one of the columns of the list.

I was alarmed to find that many of the items I get from `GetListItems` have a person that is not listed in the result of calling `GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb`.

Why would this happen and how do I fix it, or should I be using something other than `GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb` as a definitive list of all people who might be stored in a person column of that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than call `GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb`, get the list items for "UserInfo":

```
GetListItems("UserInfo", null, null, null, "100000", null, null);
```